# Adding Parameters to VBA HTTP Post Request

Tags: vba, excel

I want to request a token from a web service. It requires I make an HTTP "POST" request using an authorization code.

I need to include this code, among other parameters in my request.

Any detail I find online formats the request in Java as follows (all IDs are faked):

```
POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: "YourURL.com" 
grant_type=authorization_code&code=aPrxsmIEeqM9PiQroGEWx1UiMQd95_5JUZ
VEhsOFhS8EVvbfYBBJli2W5fn3zbo.8hojaNW_1g%3D%3D&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNI
NVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82HnFVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCs
cA9GE&client_secret=1955279925675241571&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fcode_callback.jsp
```

How do I produce a request like this?

Below are the relevant components of my code:

```vb
Dim request As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim
    client_id, 
    redirect_uri,
    grant_type,
    client_secret,
    authcode,
    result,
    token_url, 
As String

Sub testmod()

    Set request = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    client_id = "MyClientID"
    client_secret = "MyClientSecret"
    grant_type = "authorization_code"
    redirect_uri = "MyRedirectURI"
    authcode = "MyAuthorizationCode"
    token_url = "MyTokenURL" <--- No specified query string appended

    With request
        .Open method:="POST", Url:=token_url
        ''''Including POST Params with Send method''''
        .Send ("{""code"":" & authcode & 
        ",""grant_type"":authorization_code,""client_id"":" & client_id & 
        ",""client_secret"":" & client_secret & ",""redirect_uri"":" & 
        redirect_uri & "}")
        ''''This returns error code 400 denoting a bad request''''
        Debug.Print .StatusText
    end with

end sub
```

Any idea why these parameters are causing this request to fail?

Comment: Pretty sure a POST request body shouldn't have the `{` and `}` that you have at the beginning and end nor the literal double quotes `"` that you have surrounding the key names.

Comment: Additionally I would suggest that if you are going to me messing around with http requests/responses that you check out [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as I have found it very helpful to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what API you are referring to, whereas there is a new API in which the oldest 'guide' is dated 'Mar' presumably 2019.

```
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/apis 
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/guides
```

Wherein there is NO reference to the "&client_secret=" being needed !.
In the 'latest' API, you request the 'code' as follows directly into your browser.  It is good got a very few minutes.

```
https://auth.tdameritrade.com/oauth?
```

client_id=XXXX@AMER.OAUTHAP&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://192.168.0.100

The response appears in the browser's entry, not in the body, You have to decode the response to use the 'code'. The RefreshToken (90 days valid) & AccessToken (30 minutes valid)  are used as the are returned in the ResponseText

To get the 90 day RefreshToken and the first AccessToken
This is VBA which calls Javascript.

```vb
Private Sub Get_RefreshToken()  'Good for 90 days, then needs a new 'code', see above, also get the first AccessToken which are good for 30 minutes
    Dim code As String  'dcoded, not URL coded    'WAITS for the RESPONSE, NO callback
    Dim shtSheetToWork As Worksheet
    Set shtSheetToWork = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AUTH")  '<<== may NEED change
    With shtSheetToWork
        authorizationcode = .Range(3, "C")  // dump into Excel and decode by rows  JSON 'split' 
    
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim scriptControl As Object
    Dim Response, JsonObj As Object

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    scriptControl.Language = "JScript"
    authUrl = "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/oauth2/token"
    
    xmlhttp.Open "Post", authUrl, False
    xmlhttp.Send "{grant_type: authorization_code, authorizationcode: ,access_type: offline, client_id: .UserId, redirect_uri: .URLredirect}"
    Response = scriptControl.Eval(xmlhttp.responseText)
    
        .Range(4, "C") = Response.refresh_token 'RefreshToken
        
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", Response.refresh_token
    xmlhttp.Send

    MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)
    Select Case xmlhttp.Status
         Case 200
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim strKey As String
            Dim strVal As Variant
            Dim JsonData As Variant
            
            JsonObj = JsonDate.Parse(xmlhttp.responseText)
            Cells(colstr, toprow - 1) = JsonObj
                i = 1
                Do While Trim(Cells(i, 1)) <> ""
                     Name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Text, ":")
                    If Name = "RefreshToken" Then .RefreshToken = Name: .nextRefreshToken = DateAdd("d", 90, Now)
                    If Name = "AccessToken" Then .AccessToken = Name: .nextAccessToken = DateAdd("m", 30, Now)
                                 
         Case 400
                MsgBox (" validation problem suthorization 'CODE' ")
Stop
         Case 401
                MsgBox (" Invalid credentials ")
Stop
         Case 403
                MsgBox (" caller doesn't have access to the account ")
Stop
         Case 405
                MsgBox (" Response without Allow Header")
Stop
         Case 500
                MsgBox (" unexpected server error ")
Stop
         Case 503
                MsgBox ("temporary problem responding, RETRYING !!  ")
                '   WAIT A MINUTE AND RETRY
                
     End Select
    
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    Set JsonObj = Nothing
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub AccessToken()     'WAITS for the RESPONSE, NO callback
    Dim code As String  'dcoded, not URL coded
    Dim shtSheetToWork As Worksheet
    Set shtSheetToWork = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AUTH")  '<<== may NEED change
 With shtSheetToWork
    
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim scriptControl As Object
    Dim Response, JsonObj As Object

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    scriptControl.Language = "JScript"
    authUrl = "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/oauth2/token"
    
    xmlhttp.Open "Post", authUrl, False
    xmlhttp.Send "{grant_type: refresh_token, authorizationcode: .RefreshToken, access_type: , client_id: .MYUserId, redirect_uri: }"
    Response = scriptControl.Eval(xmlhttp.responseText)
    .AccessToken = Response.refresh_token
        
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", RefreshToken
    xmlhttp.Send

    'MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)
    Select Case xmlhttp.Status
         Case 200
            Dim i As Integer
            Private strKey As String
            Private strVal As Variant
            Private Data As Variant
            
            JsonObj = Json.Parse(xmlhttp.responseText)
            Cells(colstr, toprow - 1) = JsonObj
            NextText = Cells(colstr, toprow - 1)
            JsonObj = Nothing

                i = 1
                Do While Trim(Cells(i, 1)) <> ""
                     Name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Text, ":")
                    If Name = "RefreshToken" Then .RefreshToken = Name: .nextRefreshToken = DateAdd("d", 90, Now)
                    If Name = "AccessToken" Then .AccessToken = Name: .nextAccessToken = DateAdd("m", 30, Now)
                                 
         Case 400
                MsgBox (" validation problem suthorization 'CODE' ")
Stop
         Case 401
                MsgBox (" Invalid credentials ")
Stop
         Case 403
                MsgBox (" caller doesn't have access to the account ")
Stop
         Case 405
                MsgBox (" Response without Allow Header")
Stop
         Case 500
                MsgBox (" unexpected server error ")
Stop
         Case 503
                MsgBox ("temporary problem responding, RETRYING !!  ")
                '   WAIT A MINUTE AND RETRY
                
     End Select
                Next i
                
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
 End With
End Sub
```